# Is it possible to have a maven build write a file when it fails?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-2, maven-3

I have a maven build running in a Jenkins job.

I need to do some post-processing stuff after the maven build but during the job, and so I'm running mvn with the -fn (--fail-never) option (jenkins will halt the job immediately otherwise).

The catch, of course, is that if the maven build step failed, I need to fail the job in a subsequent build step.

In the past I've done this sort of thing by writing a file to a certain location if the build failed, and then using the Ant  task to fail the build. So this is the approach I'm going for.

Is it possible to get maven to write a file on build failure?

Comment: I would suggest to use the configuration jenkins is capable of. Running a post-build-action in case of successful execution of the build and don't use --fail-never option.

Comment: @khmarbaise: That's a decent idea... I'm going to run with it and see if it makes sense. Can you post this as an answer so you can get credit if it works out for me?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the maven runner in Jenkin, you could execute the build as a shell script, then do something like...

```
mvn -q -fn clean verify || touch build_failed
```

Comment: This would technically work, however it assumes the slave has bash or sh installed, so would fail on Windows-based slaves. Also it would prevent me from using the features of the maven plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the configuration jenkins is capable of. Running a post-build-action in case of successful execution of the build and don't use --fail-never option. 
[image: enter Configuration of a execution regardless of the condition.]